# GSON 2.2.4 throwing error on a JSON containing values starting with a # sign

Tags: exception, character, gson

I'm stumped as to what may be the problem. I'm using GSON (2.2.4) to serialize/deserialize simple json objects and arrays, which I display in a JTable. Everything works fine but when I feed a json object like this:

> {"1":{"336":"#1700EB","17":"#EB0000","10":"#EB0000","26":"#1700EB","3":"#1700EB","1":"#EB0000"}}

it throws this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 71
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
```

When I remove the pound signs, it functions normally.

Here's the code that does the conversion:

```
Map<String, String> conv = null;
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
ListMultimap<String, Object> returnMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();    

    try {
        conv = g.fromJson(parse, type);

        for(String key : conv.keySet()) {
           returnMap.put("Key", key);
           returnMap.put("Value", conv.get(key));
        }

    } catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
        type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        conv = g.fromJson(parse, type);

        for(Object key : conv.keySet()) {
           returnMap.put("Key", key);
           returnMap.put("Value", conv.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Please note that I am working on a "legacy" application and I have little control over the values that come to the part of the code I'm working on; which is why I have that odd try-catch block.

Most users of this application are not savvy enough to treat their strings/jsons with the express purpose of avoiding tripping exceptions like the one outlined here (e.g. not including the # sign when passing it through the application; but adding it back when they need it), so I'd really like to fix it within the code.

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to add an important detail. What I'm doing with the code is display data in tabular form. When a user selects a cell, it handles according to context. In the context of a cell containing a json object or array, it uses the code above to extract the values from the json and passes it as the new table data for the table's model. So, the sample json object should ideally come out like this (imagine table form)

**336 | #1700EB
17  | #EB0000
10  | #EB0000
26  | #1700EB
3   | #1700EB
1   | #EB0000**

...but it doesn't get there. The previous table that had the cell with the json object looked like this:

**1 | {336=#1700EB, 17=#EB0000, 10=#EB0000, 26=#1700EB, 1=#EB0000}**

Does this form have anything to do with the error? I understand that the json object form should be like this (at least the ones I work with): **{"336":"#1700EB"...}**. That's probably my only hunch as to what may be wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you're attempting to Map that JSON to a `Map<String, String>` which in no way does it resemble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying guys. I was able to fix the problem though, honestly, I still don't know the underlying cause. Anyway, I refactored the code to not do the initial attempt to map using Type. Apparently, it caused the problem further downstream.

Here's the amended code for the curious:

```
Map<String, Object> conv = null;
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
ListMultimap<String, Object> returnMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();    

conv = g.fromJson(parse, type);
for(Object key : conv.keySet()) {
    returnMap.put("Key", key);
    Object check = conv.get(key.toString());
    if ((check.toString().startsWith("{") && check.toString().endsWith("}")) || 
            (check.toString().startsWith("[") && check.toString().endsWith("]")))
        check = g.toJson(check);
        returnMap.put("Value", check);
}


return returnMap;
```